# Insert not working in Spring MVC

Tags: hibernate, spring-mvc

### My Question:

I have created a Spring MVC application, which is using Hibernate.
My table `Person` is getting created, but the data which I supply from the view is not getting inserted. I browsed through many sites, but am not being able to point out my mistake.

### Here are my files:

This is the HomeController, where I have specified
two request mappings, one for the root and another fort the save method**

```
    package com.controller;   

    @Controller              
    public class MainController {           
        @Autowired            
        private PersonService ps;           
        @RequestMapping("/")   

        public String home() {
            return "index";         }

        @RequestMapping(value="/save",method=RequestMethod.POST)
        public String save(@ModelAttribute Person p) {
            ps.save(p);
            return "index";        
        }        
    }
```

---

This is the PersonDAOClass, which contains the save method

```
    package com.dao;        
    import com.model.Person;        
    public interface PersonDAO {
        public void save(Person p);
    }
```

---

Here is the Implementation of DAO:

```
    @Transactional
    @Repository
    public class PersonDAOImpl implements PersonDAO{
        @Autowired
        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;          
        public void save(Person p) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            Session s = sessionFactory.openSession();   
            sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        //  Transactional tx = (Transactional) s.beginTransaction();
            s.persist(p);
            s.flush();
            s.close();
        }       
    }
```

---

This is my service class

```
    package com.service;        

    import com.model.Person;        
    public interface PersonService {
        public void save(Person p);
    }
```

---

This is serviceImpl of the service

```
package com.service;  

@Service
public class PersonServiceImpl implements PersonService{
    @Autowired
    private PersonDAO pdao;     
    public void setPersonDAO(PersonDAO personDAO) {
        this.pdao = personDAO;      }

    @Transactional
    public void save(Person p) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        this.pdao.save(p);
    }       
}
```

---

Finally, this is my index.jsp

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <meta charset="utf-8">
            <title>Welcome</title>
        </head> 
        <body>
        <h2>Hello World!</h2>
            <form action="save" >
            <!-- id : <input type="text" name="id"> -->
            name : <input type="text" name="name"> <input type="submit"
                value="submit">
        </form>

        </body>
    </html>
```

Comment: Add annotation `@Service` to `PersonDAO`.

Comment: thanks a lot! Problem Solved

Comment: despite there's almost no difference, you have to use `@Repository` instead. The `@Service` annotation is for Service layer, the `@Repository` for the DAO one